# Как убрать теги из запроса ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Есть ajax запрос в js файле на выполнение скрипта php. Результат выполнения нужно вывести в консоль в виде:

```
Фамилия1 Имя1 Счёт1
Фамилия2 Имя2 Счёт2
```

Но по ходу выполнения моего кода выходит это:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Фамилия1</td>
        <td>Имя1</td>
        <td>Счёт1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Фамилия2</td>
        <td>Имя2</td>
        <td>Счёт2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Запрос ajax:

```
 var tutajax = $.ajax("dobavl.php") 
            .done(function(data) { 
                    console.log(data); 
            })
        .fail(function() { 
            console.log("ne ochen"); 
            });
```

Код PHP:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'тут логин', 'тут пароль')
    or die('Не удалось соединиться: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('vladiksan1998') or die('Не удалось выбрать базу данных');

$query = 'SELECT fname, sname, score FROM records';
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Запрос не удался: ' . mysql_error());

echo "<table>\n";
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "\t<tr>\n";
    foreach ($line as $col_value) {
        echo "\t\t <td> $col_value </td> \n";
    }
    echo "\t</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";
mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Хочу отметить, что качество Ваших вопросов растет на глазах.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант 1. Переделать код PHP, чтобы он возвращал данные в нужном формате/виде.

Вариант 2. Не переделывать код PHP:

```
var tutajax = $.ajax("dobavl.php") 
  .done(function(data) { 
    $(data).find("tr").each(function() {
      var rowValues = [];
      $(this).find("td").each(function(){
        rowValues.push($(this).text());
      });
      console.log(rowValues.join(" "));
    });
  }) 
  .fail(function() { 
    console.log("ne ochen"); 
  });
```

Comment: Не помогло. Выводит всё равно так же как и было

Comment: @ВладКислюк В вопросе нет кода, выводящего результат `ajax`-а в консоль.

Comment: Извиняюсь. Сейчас исправлю

Comment: @ВладКислюк Вы не обновили код на клиенте.

Comment: А вот и нет. Как раз таки я всё обновил, но выводит всё так же как и раньше. В формате указанным в вопросе.

Comment: @ВладКислюк Этого не может быть. То, что Вы видите в консоли, туда выводит какой-то другой код.

Comment: `var tutajax2 = $.ajax("otobr.php") 
  .done(function(data) { 
    $(data).find("tr").each(function() {
      var rowValues = [];
      $(this).find("td").each(function(){
        rowValues.push($(this).text());
      });
      console.log(rowValues.join(" "));
    });
  }) 
  .fail(function() { 
    console.log("ne ochen"); 
  }); `вот код. Если бы мог прикрепить скрин консоли я бы сделал это

Comment: @ВладКислюк Очень хорошо. Это код из моего ответа.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78026/discussion-between---and-igor).

Answer (score 1):

#### Вариант 1:

Можно задать порядок выборки полей в запросе:

```
$query = 'SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM records';
```

Где, field1 - имя, field2 - фамилия, field3 - целое число
Тогда при выводе полей в цикле будет определяться последовательность полей так, как ты их задал в запросе

#### Вариант 2:

При выводе ассоциативного массива указывать поля:

```
echo "<table>\n";
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "\t<tr>\n";
    echo "\t\t<td>" . $line['field1'] . "</td>\n";
    echo "\t\t<td>" . $line['field2'] . "</td>\n";
    echo "\t\t<td>" . $line['field3'] . "</td>\n";
    echo "\t</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";
```

Comment: Первый способ не помог. Выводит так же как и прежде. При попытке сделать второй ругается на строку: `echo "\t\t<td>$line['field1']</td>\n";` А ругается оно вот так: `syntax error, unexpected $EOF, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING`

Comment: Обновил второй пример, попробуй. Вынес вывод элементов массива

Comment: Всё равно, так же выводит